# Why doesn't this SCR diode work?

Tags: transistors, diodes

I was helping my kids with this circuit in their Elenco Snap Circuits kit.  It doesn't work.  U2 is a simple audio IC, and I verified that it is connected correctly to the speaker and batteries (when I use a jumper to bypass Q3 to the input, it turns on as expected).  The resistor is 10k.
The kit describes Q3 as an SCR, which I think is a silicon rectifier diode.  The circuit is supposed to...

1. Begin off.
2. Turn on as soon as the jumper wire from point A to B is removed.

But when we try it, nothing happens.

**How would I test the SCR, and/or is there a reason that the circuit would not operate as intended?**. I do have a digital multimeter that I could use to test it.
[image]

Comment: Would you mind measuring the voltage between the battery (-) and the C3 point (between Q3 and U2), when initially powered on, after the jumper is removed, and after the jumper is reapplied? (same for point B1)

Comment: Check the polarity of everything and make sure it matches

Answer (score 0):

Q3 must be defective.

Try this:

- Insert jumper wire A to B
- Remove U2 alarm IC
- Remove SP speaker
- Add new resistor from C3 to E3 (1k to 10k is fine)
- Place DMM probes on C3 and E3 in voltage measurement mode
- Verify zero volts on readout

Now remove jumper wire and check voltage from DMM again. If it stays at zero volts, then the Q3 part is defective.